# How to use map with urljoin?

Tags: python, dictionary, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a list of relatives URLs, and I need the complete URL.
I'm using scrapy.

I can get one URL with

```
urljoin(response.url,url_list[0])
```

but I want to apply the function to the whole list, I've tried this:

```
map(urljoin,response.url,url_list)
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with a list comprehension - more readable and actually faster:

```
[urljoin(response.url, url) for url in url_list]
```

But if you still want to do it with `map()`, you would need to use [`functools.partial()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial

map(partial(urljoin, response.url), url_list)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from urlparse import urljoin
>>> from functools import partial
>>> 
>>> >>> url_list = ["1", "2", "3"]
>>> map(partial(urljoin, "https://google.com"), url_list)
['https://google.com/1', 'https://google.com/2', 'https://google.com/3']
```

Answer (score 2):

It does not work, because `map` expects a function and one or few sequences, so that the function is applied to corresponding elements of those sequences. So, in your example, `response.url` is interpreted as a sequence. I think, the simplest and most readable way is to avoid `map` altogether:

```
[urljoin(response.url, url) for url in url_list]
```